# How to find all the checked nodes in a Treeview using C#

Tags: c#, treeview

**This is the code which I am using, but I am always getting a blank string from the function.**

How do I solve such a problem?

```
private string GetArrayofCheckedNodes()
{
    string arrCheckedNodes = "";
    ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
    foreach (TreeNode node in TreeView1.Nodes)
    {
        if (node.Checked == true) // Checking whether a node is checked or not.
        {
            al.Add(node.Text);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < al.Count; i++)
    {
        arrCheckedNodes += al[i].ToString() + " , ";
    }
    return arrCheckedNodes;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want ALL checked nodes. `TreeView1.Nodes` only returns the first level so you will need to recurse down the tree. Also, you can use `string.Join()` to join the resultant values together.

```
private string GetArrayofCheckedNodes()
{
    return string.Join(" , ", GetCheckedNodes(treeView1.Nodes));
}

public List<string> GetCheckedNodes(TreeNodeCollection nodes)
{
    List<string> nodeList = new List<string>();
    if (nodes == null)
    {
        return nodeList;
    }

    foreach (TreeNode childNode in nodes)
    {
        if (childNode.Checked)
        {
            nodeList.Add(childNode.Text);
        }
        nodeList.AddRange(GetCheckedNodes(childNode.Nodes));
    }
    return nodeList;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, there was a slight mistake before. I've corrected it now!